# Update Contact List

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a Google Sheet (not shown as with confidential information) with column 1 showing "Yes" or "No" and column 12 showing names of contacts. We want our Google Form to only show contacts who are marked "Yes." All data begins in row 2 (row 1 are headings):

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EGDkFS-V7DaouaU1sj6HMxYGLc1l4Q21fptJio3ukV4')
const tutorsSheet = ws.getSheetByName("Current Tutors");
const tutorNames = 
tutorsSheet.getRange(2,12,tutorsSheet.getLastRow()-1,12).getDisplayValues();

var tutorList = tutorNames.filter(row=>row[0]=="Yes").map(row => row[12])
trainedtutors = tutorList.filter(row => row !== '')

const tutorNameQuestion = form.getItemById ("1266932508")
tutorNameQuestion.asListItem().setChoiceValues(trainedtutors)
```

However, the error message tells us there's an empty array for the last line of code shown above. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Starting on wrong column

This: `const tutorNames =  tutorsSheet.getRange(2,12,tutorsSheet.getLastRow()-1,12).getDisplayValues();`

should be this: `const tutorNames =  tutorsSheet.getRange(2,1,tutorsSheet.getLastRow()-1,12).getDisplayValues();`

#### Incorrect index

This: `var tutorList = tutorNames.filter(row=>row[0]=="Yes").map(row => row[12])`

should be this: `var tutorList = tutorNames.filter(row=>row[0]=="Yes").map(row => row[11])`